# How to make a lucene analyzer more strict?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a custom `lucene analyzer` for names.
I mostly get the correct match back, but I would like to prevent the return of results that are "not so close" matched.

Example:

Query: `Art Inn Hotel Essen`

One of the result: `Hotel Garni an der Eissporthalle`, score: 7.6011443

I'd like to prevent this "result", even though it is not the topmost, it is still inappropriate. Is that possible?

I use the following matcher:

```
public class MyAnalyzer {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, java.io.Reader reader) {
        VERSION = Version.LUCENE_4_9;
        final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(VERSION, reader);
        TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(VERSION, source);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(VERSION, result);
        result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    }
}

BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(new QueryParser(VERSION, "name", new MyAnalyzer()).parse(name), Occur.MUST);
```

Also I wonder: why is the result matched at all? Because the only term that occurs in both of them is the string `Hotel`?

Comment: Could you add some examples of results that are more appropriate? Because since you asked for documents containing Hotel, "Hotel Garni an der Eissporthalle" definitely matches as one of the words is Hotel.

Comment: Yes I know it qualifies for the result as it contains "hotel", though it does not contain the 3 other words and also has some additional words, thats why lucene should consider it as inappropriate. Closer matches would be for example `Art Inn Essen`